# How to send a template to another template without declaring the type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using

I'm trying to compile following code :

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct Container1;//forward declaration
template<class T> struct Container2;//forward declaration

template<class Container,class Type>
using _Make_Container=typename Container<Type>;

template<class T>
struct Container1
{};

template<class T>
struct Container2
{};

int main()
{
    _Make_Container<Container1,int> a;
}
```

Which give me some errors:

```
 expected nested-name-specifier before 'Container'
  using _Make_Container=typename Container<Type>;
                                ^
 error: 'Container' is not a template
```

It seems OK to me because we send `Container1` and `int` to `using` Then it becomes :

```
using _Make_Container=typename Container1<int>;
//then 
Container1<int> a;
```

I can't understand the reason for that errors !! Any idea?

Is there any way for making that works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those error messages are pretty clear.

> expected nested-name-specifier before 'Container'
>
> ```
>  using _Make_Container=typename Container<Type>;
>                           ^
> ```

You're not referring to a nested dependent type so there's no need for the `typename` keyword here. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords?rq=1) for a detailed explanation on where `typename` is required.

> error: 'Container' is not a template

Just like it says, your alias template doesn't indicate `Container` is a template, but then it proceeds to use it as one. You need to use a template template parameter for `Container`

```
template<template<typename> class Container,class Type>
using _Make_Container = Container<Type>;
```

And borrowing Yakk's [excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063027/how-to-send-a-template-to-another-template-without-declaring-the-type/24063355#comment37104561_24063137), you should change the alias template definition to

```
template<template <typename...> class T1, typename... T2>
using Make_Container = T1<T2...>;
```

This lets you do the following:

```
template<class T, class T1>
struct Container2
{};

Make_Container<Container2,int,long> b;
```

---

Finally, names using a leading underscore followed by an upper case letter are [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) by the implementation. So you should rename `_Make_Container` to `Make_Container`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the alias template like [this](http://ideone.com/2s9yTx)

```
template<template <typename> class T1,class T2>
using _Make_Container= T1<T2>;
```

Comment: I prefer the alternative with more `class` : `template<class>class T1`.  Also sometimes `template<class...>class T1` is wise, as the way `template`s match is sort of backwards.

Comment: @Yakk `class`ical Yakk :P

Answer (score 1):

```
template< template <class> class Container,class Type>
using _Make_Container = Container<Type>;
```